Webview: Constraints towards the top and bottom is being removed when viewing a URL containing a PDF
I'm not quite sure what really is causing my problem. But the issue is that I have this mobile application built with Swift as a WebView. Everything works great when using the application. But I do have a section where a user can view their messages. When a user touches on a message, they are being navigated to a PDF. This means that this PDF is also covering the entire screen. Before a user presses the message, there's a SafeArea at the top and bottom. You can clearly see a background-color outside the SafeArea. But as soon as you enter this PDF-file, the background-color is gone. I have also added a button as a subview on top of the PDF. This is so the user can navigate back. When the user navigates back though, this SafeArea seems to be gone (it is removed as soon as you display the PDF). Because now the content goes all the way to the top and bottom. No longer within the previous constraints.
Before I view one of the messages. I can see in the "Debug View Hierarchy" that there's a WKScrollView covering the entire page. Then there's a WKContentView that doesn't reach the top (like it's within the SafeArea).
As soon as I view a PDF and go back. If I then view this "Debug View" again, I can see that the WKContentView is as large as the WKScrollView. My guess is that this is what causing the behaviour.
The problem won't fix itself if I don't restart the app.
Any ideas?
The Storyboard Inspector looks like:
View Controller Scene
View Controller
View
Safe Area
Here's the code that I use.

import UIKit
import WebKit

var isLoggedIn = false

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let webView: WKWebView(frame: CGReact(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

    var loginURL = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.my-url.com")!)
    var messagesURL = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.my-url.com/messages")!)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubView(webView)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleAppDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        webView.load(loginURL)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        webView.frame = view.bounds
    }

    @objc func handleAppDidBecomeActive() {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        webView.load(loginURL)
      }
    }

    // This function is called when the user clicks the "Back to messages" button
    @objc func backToMessages() {
      let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100)

      if viewWithTag != nil {
        viewWithTag?.removeFromSuperview()
        webView.load(messagesURL)
      } else {
        NSLog("No view found with tag 100")
      }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
      let url = navigationAction.request.url
      let urlStr = url?.absoluteString

      if (!urlStr.contains("referrer_url") && urlStr.contains("session_token")){
        isLoggedIn = true
      } else if (urlStr!.contains("logout")) {
        isLoggedIn = false
      }

      if (urlStr!.starts(with: "authenticator:///")){
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!)) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url!)
        } else {
          NSLog("Can't open Authenticator")
          decisionHandler(.cancel)
        }
      }

      // This is when a user get's navigated to a PDF-file
      if (urlStr!.starts(with: "blob:")){
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 70, width: 100, height: 300))
        button.setTitle("Back to messages", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backToMessages), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tag = 100
        self.view.addSubview(button)
      }

      decisionHandler(.allow)
    }
}

Since I'm not familiar with Xcode nor Swift. I've been trying to change a lot of properties and stuff. I've tried to use ChatGPT to solve the issue. It always tells me that I should modify the constraints. I tried to add the code beneath to both the viewDidLoad() function, and to the backToMessages() function. But it didn't solve it
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
])

